# How to blur face don't using opencv?

Tags: python

I have detect the faces using MTCNN.
It's detect faces in the pictures well.
I want to blur detected faces.
I tried that using cv2.
But I can't implement that.
Do you have a good idea?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
import numpy as np
import os

def draw_image_with_boxes(filename, result_list):
data = pyplot.imread(filename)
pyplot.imshow(data)
ax = pyplot.gca()
for result in result_list:
    x, y, width, height = result['box']
    rect = Rectangle((x, y), width, height, color='gray')
    ax.add_patch(rect)
pyplot.show()

filename = 'https://prnt.sc/uli1ge'
pixels = pyplot.imread(filename)
ax = pyplot.gca()
detector = MTCNN()
faces = detector.detect_faces(pixels)
draw_image_with_boxes(filename, faces)
```

Comment: If the image is stored as some n-dimensional array, simply convolve a blurring kernel over the relevant portions of the image using scipy.signal.convolve2d or similar. Blurring is just essentially assigning each pixel in the blurred region the average pixel value (across all color channels) of some selection of neighboring pixels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Could you explain more details?